# Redirection with multiple variables

Tags: php, redirect

i have this code that enables to redirec with a single parameter that comes from the origianl URL  - i am looking for a solution that will lalow me to grab several parameters from the link, and populate them to the redirected link, how do i do that?

```
function redirect() {
    var sub = getSub();
    var country = sGeobytesInternet;
    if (country == "US") {
        window.location = "https://bondika.com/click?pid=17&offer_id=8693&sub1=creative1"+sub
    } else if (country == "NL"){
        window.location = "https://bondika.com/click?pid=17&offer_id=8693&sub1=creative1"+sub
    } else {
        window.location = "http://www.ynet.co.il/"
    }
}   

function getSub() {
    regex = /subid=([\w-]*)/;
    url = window.location.href;
    if (-1 != url.indexOf("subid")) {
        var id = url.match(regex)[1];
        return id;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
redirect()
```

Comment: For us to help, list out the parameters you want to get from the URL

Comment: This seems like a javascript question, not a PHP question.

Comment: Hey there! I noticed that you tried to add some code into your question. It would be super helpful if you could edit this question and wrap your code with three ` symbols on either side of it. One set in the beginning, one set at the end. Also consider formatting your code for easier reading. This will help other StackOverflow users answer your question with less headache. Thanks for the contribution, and good luck finding an answer!

Comment: @GrandPhuba -  I want to send a link with these parameters:

email={email_address}
phone={phone_number}
state={state_name}

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

You can use the following function to get the parameters in the URL

```
function getParameters(){
    return new Map(window.location.search.slice(1).split('&').map((param)=>{
       const [key, value] = param.split('=')
       return [key, decodeURIComponent(value|| '')]
    }))
}
```

To use:

```
const parameters = getParameters()
const email = paramaters.get('email')
const phone = paramaters.get('phone')
const state = paramaters.get('state')
```

To redirect using plain JS, you can do any of the following (note these are similar, but necessarily the same)

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
window.location.assign("http://stackoverflow.com");
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Putting it all together:

```
function getParameters(){
    const parameters = new Map(window.location.search.slice(1).split('&').map((param)=>{
       const [key, value] = param.split('=')
       return [key, decodeURIComponent(value|| '')]
    }))
}
function redirect(){    
    // GET PARAMETERS FROM CURRENT URL
    const parameters = getParameters()
    const email = paramaters.get('email')
    const phone = paramaters.get('phone')
    const state = paramaters.get('state')
    
    // BUILD URL HERE
    const BASE_URL = 'https://my_domain.com/'
    let redirect_url = BASE_URL
    if(email){
        redirect_url += `?email=${email}`
    } 
    ...
    
    // REDIRECT
    window.location.href = redirect_url
}
redirect()
```

Comment: Note that I did not intend the resulting `redirect` function as final. You'll have to modify it so it build the redirect URL accordingly, but you should get the essence here.